# Automatic style adding to every html, Apache2 Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.04, apache2, localhost

I got little curious problem. In every html I create and add path to apache will system add automatically style into my  (vis picture). What is more surprising that other css external files stop working, and comes with the msg in all browsers "stylesheet could not been load" even that all is in the file root and path in the browser works. I tried to uninstall all global dependencies for npm, check system with NeoPi and check my public IP, all is fine. I reinstalled apache, php, mysql and all involved in localhost, problem still comes.

In localhost I overwrite adserver.com and install it globally ad-server npm, somewhere from this moment problems start appering.
 [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLShQ.png)

Comment: Do you have any adblocker plugins in your browser?

Comment: Are you kidding, fantastic.  It works :), do not know what to say. Thank you +1